# Blogger: Labeling Sections on the Layout Page

Tags: blogger

I've created a responsive theme for Blogger. Thus, since the Layout page shows is a reflection of the actual layout, but doesn't make use of media queries. Everything is lined up vertically at 100% width in the admin area(which is expected).

My question: is there a way that I can label the sections somehow so that the labels show up on the layout page, but not when viewing the site? Currently when viewing the layout page, there are 8 sections that say "Add a Gadget", and the user has no way of knowing which section is what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Years later, the correct answer is now outdated and no longer works. However, Google added support for naming sections by simply adding the attribute: `name="NameOFSectionHere"` to the widget section.

Complete example for naming your header section "New Header" in the "admin > layout":

```
<b:section id='header' name='New Header' showaddelement='true'>
```

Answer (score 8):

YES!!! You can change ANYTHING to do with the look and style (including title) of the Layout page (admin page) without effecting the look and style of the actual site.

To answer your question about the titles of the layout page. Say for example, you have a TEXT widget and you want to change the title of "TEXT" to an actual title in the layout but not in the actual site:

1. Find the ID of the widget (in the template) that you want to address: "Template" > "Jump to Widget" > "Text1".

All the widgets listed in the "Jump to widget" are the ID's you wish to use based on which one you wish to address.

2. Above the "/b:skin" use CSS to style the titles as you see fit (ID's start with "#" so make sure you add this in front of the widget ID):

   ```
   #layout #text1 .title {
   display:block !important;
   }
   #text1 .title {
   display:none;
   }
   ```

You can use the same method to change and style anything in the layout section by using the code "#layout" before your CSS codes. Say, for example, you adjust the height of the header and it automatically adjusted the layout section (admin section) but it's causing too much space between the header section and the blog section in the Layout.

Do this:

```
    #header {
    height:147px;
    }

    #layout #header {
    height: 0px !important;
    }
```

To adjust the entire layout, say width for example, use:

```
     body #layout {
     width: 700px !important; 
     }
```

If you don't see the changes right away on the Layout page, after you save the template, click the refresh button  while on the layout page.

**EDIT: (snapshots of tested answer)**

[image: snapshot of layout with title of widget showing]

As you can see the title of the widget shows up on the layout page but not the actual site:
[image: widget with title not showing on actual site]

Comment: This method does not seem to work. I have tried and tried. For example, I hard-coded Flexslider into the template, and wish to hide it within the admin section so that it doesn't disrupt the layout. So I used: #layout .flexslider {display: none}; , but nothing has changed. I checked the console.log and it is not being applied.

Comment: The only thing you will find on the layout page (admin page) are widgets. Widgets are the boxes that show up in the Layout. All your widgets can be found by going:  "Template" > "Jump to Widget" >

Comment: If you are not seeing it in the widget list: "Jump to Widget" than it's not in the Layout. Likely your Flexslider is within a widget called "HTML/ Javascript" which can be identified as "HTML1" or "HTML2" etc... You have to use the widget ID in which the slider is within.

Comment: As a result, what you want to do is identify which "HTML" number your slider is within and do this: #layout #HTML1 {display:none !important;}. Anything with the layout, you must put "!important". Does that help?

Comment: I coded flexslider into the template, it is not within a widget. I tried hiding my LinkList just for testing, it does not work. I used: #layout .LinkList { display: none !important; }.

Comment: All widgets, will always be ID's not Classes. Change the class name ".LinkList" to ID name "#LinkList". Also, if the flexslider is not within a widget, no code at all, not even the HTML code, then it would have no effect on the Layout page.

Comment: Dude, I'm not sure you should be giving advice on this. There are classes and id's for each widget. Example straight from the source: <div class="widget LinkList" id="LinkList1">. Also, If flexslider has no code at all, how would it show up when viewed then? Think about what you are saying before you say it. Like I said 3 times already, I coded it into the template(HTML & CSS), but not into a widget. It doesn't have to be in a widget. I designed this theme(template) from scratch. If your method worked, it wouldn't matter if it was in a widget or not. Either it works, or it doesn't.

Comment: Have you tested your solution yourself recently? Maybe something has changed(blogger did revamp their editor about 2 months ago).

Comment: Yes, I tested it before I posted the answer for you. The classes in the widgets refer to the type of widget it is, the ID's in the widgets refer to that specific widget. This is very basic Blogger stuff.

Comment: Also, if all the coding for your slider is in the template only and no code exists within a widget on the layout page, then it wouldn't effect the layout page because the layout page only shows widgets. Hence "Add a Gadget" means to add a widget. If you designed the Blogger template from scratch then the layout page would only contain the widgets in which you added, if you didn't add any then the only widget that would appear in the layout page is the Blog1 widget, which is NEEDED for the item posts and post pages to appear on the site.

Comment: So again, it becomes very obvious that if there is no code for your slider in a widget then there would be no widget associated with the slider and therefore the slider wouldn't effect the layout page what-so-ever since the layout page is ONLY a widget page. All other codes appear in the template page, not the widget (layout) page.

Comment: If the code is hard-coded into the template(such a flexslider), it shows up on the admin layout page.

Comment: Yes, correct, if coded in such a manner, it does show up on the layout page but I was assuming you wouldn't have used such unorthodox coding otherwise the layout page becomes irrelevant and you wouldn't be asking how to modify the layout page. If you want to change the way the slider appears in the layout page, simply don't use unorthodox coding in your template and it will not show up on the layout page. Alternatively, you must associate the slider with a widget and modify the associated widget using the coding mentioned in my answer.

Comment: Nik, the slider is incorporated into the theme, because the theme is to be sold. It is not for personal use. It only shows up on the homepage. I do not want the slider to appear when reading posts. This is why it is not in a widget, nor will it ever be.

Comment: I'm a fool. I finally got this to work using your method. I dunno what happened before, I can only guess that my browser catch needed refreshing or something. Changing correct answer to this one..

Comment: No problem, I am just delighted it's working for you. Thanks for the accepted answer :)

Comment: I noticed that it still will not allow borders, box-shadows, color, font-family's, or backgrounds. It will allow content, height, display, width, padding, margin, and positioning.

Comment: Correct, because it's still only a layout page. Much like a blueprint, you wouldn't want to add "styles and looks" that dress it up. It's just a foundation framework to get an overall look of the website layout. It's a floor plan for analyzing the structure and a user-friendly way of building. Hence you can change the "style and looks" to match the skeleton of the website, but there would be no reason to change the "style and looks" to make it beautiful or pretty; that would be taking away it's purpose and function as just an easy to read layout (blueprint) page.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to style Blogger's Layout page as it strips off styles and content added by you to the template.

But you can definitely find work arounds to get this done. Since it's the Layout panel, the only ones who will be using it will be the blog admins. Install some browser extension which will allow you to add custom css to any web page and add some CSS rules specific to the blogger layout page.

I mostly use Chrome and here is how I did it.

1. Installed the Chrome Extension - https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylish/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe?hl=en
2. Now add CSS to customize the Layout page. I have a b:section for my blog footer with id `footer-3` . So I added

   `#footer-3:before{content: "footer";}`

   as the CSS and I added a rule to use the CSS only on URLS starting with http://www.blogger.com/display?blogID=11 (11  should be the Blog Id)

Now when I opened the layout page, it added the text 'footer' above the footer section.You can find similar extensions and workarounds for FireFox as well.

[image: css rules]
[image: layout page after edit]

but if you are trying to code this feature into a template, it won't help you

Answer (score 1):

The `admin section` is more commonly known as `Layout`.

From which device are you looking at the layout.If you open the blogger site from you computer having browser dimensions 1024 by 768 or greater,the layout should appear as it looks on the actual site and `not` a single line with 100% width.Even I use a responsive blogger template and not facing this issue.

Coming back to main question,there is not wayout.The title tag of a widget already existing shall give definite hints as to which location is being considered.

Comment: I don't know why I said that. Actually I have design a custom homepage for it as well, there are no columns on the homepage. Regardless, that's not the problem. I was just looking for some way to label the sections.

Comment: Also, I have added several sections(like ad placement). Types of widgets doesn't tell you what sections are what.

Comment: unfortunately,the only way to see is the title tag.

Comment: I don't think you get what I'm asking. NOT THE WIDGETS, the sections. Imagine an admin area with NO WIDGETS and several sections. I'm trying to figure out if there is a way I can label the sections somehow. I can't use CSS because the admin area is in an iframe...

Comment: plz can u give me a screenshot of what is meant by an admin area/sections :)